# Can't define an exception only in a mli file

Tags: exception, module, ocaml, signature

Ok, this is mostly about curiosity but I find it too strange.

Let's suppose I have this code

**sig.mli**

```
type t = A | B
```

**main.ml**

```
 let f = 
   let open Sig in
   function A | B -> ()
```

If I compile, everything will work.

Now, let's try to modify `sig.mli`

**sig.mli**

```
type t = A | B
exception Argh
```

and `main.ml`

**main.ml**

```
 let f = 
   let open Sig in
   function 
     | A -> ()
     | B -> raise Argh
```

And let's try to compile it :

```
> ocamlc -o main sig.mli main.ml
  File "main.ml", line 1:
  Error: Error while linking main.cmo:
  Reference to undefined global `Sig'
```

Well, is it just because I added the exception ? Maybe it means that exceptions are like functions or modules, you need a proper implementation.

But then, what if I write

**main.ml**

```
 let f = 
   let open Sig in
   function A | B -> ()
```

And try to compile ?

```
> ocamlc -o main sig.mli main.ml
>
```

It worked ! If I don't use the exception, it compiles !

There is no reason to this behaviour, right ? (I tested it on different compilers, 3.12.0, 4.00.0, 4.02.3 and 4.03.0 and all of them gave the same error)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike variants, exception is not a pure type and requires its implementation in `.ml` file.  Compile the following code with `ocamlc -dlambda -c x.ml`:

```
let x = Exit

-- the output --
(setglobal X!
  (seq (opaque (global Pervasives!))
    (let (x/1199 = (field 2 (global Pervasives!)))
      (pseudo _none_(1)<ghost>:-1--1 (makeblock 0 x/1199)))))
```

You can see `(let (x/1999 = (field 2 (global Pervasives!)))..` which means assigning the value stored in the `2`nd position of module `Pervasives`.  This is the value of `Exit`.  Exceptions have their values and therefore need `.ml`.

Variants do not require implementation.  It is since their values can be constructed purely from their type information: constructors' tag integers.  We cannot assign tag integers to exceptions (and their generalized version, open type constructors) since they are openly defined. Instead they define values for their identification in `.ml`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I still think the error message from the compiler could be improved because it's completely unclear what the problem is. ;-)

Comment: I still have a problem with the fact that if I don't use it there is no compiler error.

Comment: I'd say this is similar to C, where you can declare a function in a header and will only get linker errors as soon as you use it. Definitely unintuitive though.

Comment: @Lhooq, it is just as same as ordinary values.  At separation compilation phase, there is no problem declaring them only in `mli` files and not giving their implementation.  Linking is another story.

Answer (score 2):

To get an implementation of the exception, you need `sig.ml`. A `.mli` file is an interface file, a `.ml` file is an implementation file.

For this simple example you could just rename sig.mli to sig.ml:

```
$ cat sig.ml
type t = A | B
exception Argh
$ cat main.ml
let f = 
    let open Sig in
    function
    | A -> ()
    | B -> raise Argh
$ ocamlc -o main sig.ml main.ml
```

I don't see a problem with this behavior, though it would be nice not to have to duplicate types and exceptions between `.ml` and `.mli` files. The current setup has the advantage of being simple and explicit. (I'm not a fan of compilers being too clever and doing things behind my back.)

Comment: Dear Joffrey, that's exactly what I say. You can put a type in a `.mli` without a `.ml` and you won't have any problem. I actually added a `.ml` to overcome this problem but from camlspotter's answer you can see it was not a trivial answer. ;-)

Comment: As you can see I knew what the error was but wanted to know why the behaviour between exceptions and types was different.

Comment: By the way, glad you're glad there are more OCaml answerers. ;-)